# Is there a card which can be used to substitute for King Krush?

Tags: hearthstone

I am attempting to put together [Yong Woo's Survival Hunter a.k.a. Sekrit! deck](http://www.hearthhead.com/deck=14566/survival-hunter-a.k.a.-sekrit!). The deck utilizes the legendary card [King Krush](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=1144/king-krush) (8/8 Charge for 9) as a finisher. I have yet to obtain a King Krush, but am looking for a substitute. The best I have come up with is utilizing a [Reckless Rocketeer](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=445/reckless-rocketeer) (5/2 Charge for 6). Obviously the Reckless Rocketeer doesn't have the body or damage of King Krush, but will still deal a fair amount of damage quickly. Aside from the Reckless Rocketeer is there a solid substitute for King Krush in this deck?

[image: King Crush Hearthstone card][image: Reckless Rocketeer Hearthstone card]

Comment: Did you notice that the deck has been changed? Sylvanas and King Krush have been replaced by 2x Arcane Golem. No more legendaries, it should be easier to build up the deck now.

Comment: @Kappei thanks for pointing that out, funny that the modification was made hours after I made this post! I do like the change to Arcane Golem the [Survival Hunter deck](http://www.hearthhead.com/deck=14566/). That said, still wondering if there's a general substitute for King Krush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the deck has been changed, removing the legendaries, the author himself offered some advices to replace them, in case you wanted to play one of the previous incarnations of the deck:

> *Notes on the Legendaries*
>
> One of the goals of the deck was to make one that is not terribly hard to put together. The original version of this deck had only commons and rares. The three Legendaries in the deck are very useful and I happen to pull them out of packs so I put them into my deck. But those three cards can be replaced with any cards that gives you mid/late game pressure and damage potential. Here are options I've tried that all work well:
>
> - *Spiteful Smith*: 4/6 for 5 mana helps it stick around for board presence. Also combos very nicely with your trusty Eaglehorn Bow.
> - *Venture Co. Mercenary*: This takes advantage of the fact that the deck is light on minions. 7/6 for 5 mana forces your opponent to deal with it in some way.
> - *Reckless Rocketeer*: A bit crazy, but this helps with the damage potential problem of the deck, coming out swinging. With Freezing Trap to back it up, it has much greater chance to survive another turn.
> - *Savannah Highmane*: Good cost to stat ratio and the death rattle means you keep some board presence even after a trade.
> - *Sunwalker*: If you fail to contain the early/mid game pressure, this card can really give you the reprieve you need.